# Видео стриминг. Python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, streaming

Вопрос заключается в следующем: мне нужно создать платформу, которая будет транслировать потоковое видео с сервера в браузер клиенту. Эдакий аналог нетфликса и кучи оналайн кинотеатров в ру сегменте интернета. Проблема заключается в том, что 90% любой информации про это включает в себя только стриминг видео с вебкамеры. Может быть есть какие-то разработки, которые можно прикрутить к питону (фласку в частности), чтоб можно было пускать видео с сервера клиенту.

Comment: Весь видеостриминг в "кинотеатрах" - это тупо скачивание видеофайлов в специальном формате, вроде HLS, MPEG-DASH или чего-нибудь с добавкой DRM. Всё что нужно - просто сконвертировать видео в нужный формат (ffmpeg это умеет например), а в браузере настроить какой-нибудь js-плеер на скачивание полученных файлов. Питону здесь вообще не обязательно участвовать.

Comment: Если не требуется переключение качества на лету, можно даже тупо mp4/webm-файл в html-тег <video> запихнуть, да и всё - будет работать без единой строчки программного кода.